# the button close of my modal is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

the button close is not working

```
 <div class="modal fade show " id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" style="display: block;left: -6.5%;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="margin: 0%;">
 <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
     </div>
</div>
... 
</div></div>
```

Comment: Do you have Jquery installed? or in the CDN?

Comment: Can you show us running?

Just this modal submission part, use "https://jsfiddle.net/" to help us.
Or even the "stackoverflow" format obtained by that code for people.

You will need "html" and "js" as well.

That will help us a lot.

Comment: yeah i have the file jquery.min.js

Comment: It needs Javascript as well. Check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) out. You can use a starter template.

Comment: @Nour which bootstrap version are you using? or can you paste your whole modal html?

Comment: here is the link @RichardWillian
 https://jsfiddle.net/nourhle/aq1cLsug/#&togetherjs=IPOHSJG2kI

Comment: @RohitVerma version 4.3.1, here is the code: <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade show" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" style="display: block;left: -6.5%;"">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="margin: 0%">...

Comment: @Nour please check answer given below

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed your bootstrap.js or may be ordering problem but you can use like given below:-

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

     

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, if you notice my modal's class is "modal fade show" and i set the diplay :block; so i think it's because of this, and the problem is i can't use a button, this modal is inside a PHP condition, if the condition is satisfied the modal will appear this is why i set it as "show"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. https://jsfiddle.net/5zbtamxn/
Here I have the project working with no problems 
Maybe you are missing one of this libraries.

I thigger it this way

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" target="#exampleModalCenter">
Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Comment: the problem is this modal appears if a PHP condition is satisfied, without the attribute "show" it won't appear, then when it appears i can't close it :/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make Sure you have added the correct bootstrap libraries.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```